# Problem with bpy.context.selected_objects

Tags: scripting

I have a script which includes the line:

```
ListObjects = [ o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH' ]
print(ListObjects)
```

That works as a standalone script. But within a larger script it fails with:

`AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_objects'`

I have tried to follow the advice here: [bpy.context.selected_objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36281/bpy-context-selected-objects-context-object-has-no-attribute-selected-objects) by using:

`ListObjects = [ o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.select`]

But that fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Has the o.select attribute changed in 2.80, or am I using it incorrectly? Something to do with needing to use an override, perhaps?

Comment: `o.select_get()`, Blender 2.80 use getter and setter for some value

Comment: And if you find anything that come up with `AttributeError`. Try a simple command in interactive console, using `Ctrl`+`Space` to auto complete with keywords. Most of the time you can find a similar function due to the 2.80 API change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the thing that is you should always use `context` that passed by the operator instead of `bpy.context`. Unless you want to override *context* with the one you need in rare case.

And Blender 2.80 does change the `object.select` to its private(?) value, one should consider use `object.select_set(bool)` and `object.select_get()` for select value manipulation.

So assume that your function got a context passed in:
`ListObjects = [ o for o in context.scene.objects if o.select_get()]`
will give you a more reliable context.