# This script can't run twice, why?

Tags: scripting, objects, data-blocks

Blender ver 2.83 LTS.

Whenever I tried to run this script twice, it came out an error:

ERROR (bke.lib_id): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_lts_283\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\lib_id.c:342 id_us_min: ID user decrement error: OBNew_STL (from '[Main]'): 0 <= 0

I'm trying to delete the old STL object without selection or restarting the blender file. This error is driving me crazy but I have no idea handle it.

```
import bpy


new_stl_is_here = []


def new_stl():
    global new_stl_is_here
    #  get old object list
    old_obj_lst = []
    for j in bpy.data.objects:
        old_obj_lst.append(j)
    #  import a STL file
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath="C:\\xxx.stl")
    #  get new object list
    new_obj_lst = []
    for jj in bpy.data.objects:
        new_obj_lst.append(jj)
    #  new STL is in this list
    new_stl_is_here = list(set(new_obj_lst)-set(old_obj_lst))
    
    
def delete_old_stl():
    for jjj in bpy.data.objects:
        if jjj.name == "New_STL":
            bpy.data.objects["New_STL"].user_clear()
            bpy.data.orphans_purge()
    
    
def rename_stl(): 
    new_stl_is_here[0].name = "New_STL"
    new_stl_is_here[0].data.name = "New_STL_mesh"
    

new_stl()
delete_old_stl()
rename_stl()
```

Comment: I think you are trying to clear the users of an object that has no user. before the `user_clear` line try `if jjj.users > 0`. Also I would replace the name of the `jjj` variable by `obj`, it's more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ditch global lists and use selection**

After calling the import operator any newly imported objects are selected and make up the `context.selected_objects` list.

I don't have any multi-object stl files to test theory against, but will go thru the motions with a single object file.

With no current selection.

```
>>> C.selected_objects
[]
```

Import stl

```
>>> bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath="/home/batfinger/Desktop/untitled.stl")
Import finished in 0.0156 sec.
{'FINISHED'}
```

Newly imported object(s) (*Have no examples of multi object stls*)

```
>>> C.selected_objects
[bpy.data.objects['Untitled']]
```

Remove that import

```
>>> old_import = C.selected_objects
>>> while old_import:
...     D.objects.remove(old_import.pop())
...     
>>> C.selected_objects
[]
```

Import again

```
>>> bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath="/home/batfinger/Desktop/untitled.stl")
Import finished in 0.0140 sec.
{'FINISHED'}

>>> C.selected_objects
[bpy.data.objects['Untitled']]
```

Rename this time

```
>>> #and to rename
>>> for o in C.selected_objects:
...     o.name = "Foo"
...     
>>> C.selected_objects
[bpy.data.objects['Foo']]
```

What's the file looking like

```
>>> D.objects[:]
[bpy.data.objects['Camera'], bpy.data.objects['Foo'], bpy.data.objects['Lamp']]
```

**Notes.**

Basically think the remove method in question code is "icky", as also is keeping some global list with object references ... just asking for a crash.

Notice the way the objects were removed in python console code above. They are unlinked (de-usered) by default.

To use a list like so recommend only using names, or just not doing it that way.

**Putting this into a script**

Have made a version of the script using a custom property tag to "mark" any imported STL. And to keep the new, remove, rename order also looked at the name.. one thinks remove, new, rename makes more sense.. anyhow

```
import bpy

tag = 'IMPORTED_STL_OBJECT'

def new_stl(filepath):
    #  import a STL file
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=filepath)
    #  get new object list
    # ops use context silly not to use it.
    # could do set before / after here too.
    for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        o[tag] = 1
        o.data[tag] = 1
    
    
def delete_old_stl(name="NewSTL"):
    stls = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
            if (name and o.name.startswith(name))
            and tag in o.keys()]
    while stls:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(stls.pop())
    stl_meshes = [m for m in bpy.data.meshes
            if (name and m.name.startswith(name))
            and tag in m.keys()]
    while stl_meshes:
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(stl_meshes.pop())
            
        
def rename_stl(name="NewSTL"): 
        stls = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
            if tag in o.keys()]
        for o in stls:
            o.name = name
            o.data.name = f"{name}_Mesh"
    

new_stl("/home/batfinger/Desktop/untitled.stl")
delete_old_stl()
rename_stl()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, after tried your method things goes very well in script. Anyway... when I tried to do the same in addon, an error occurred: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_objects'. Maybe objects wouldn't be auto selected after import in addon?

Comment: Not the case if done correctly.  [Maybe related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36281/bpy-context-selected-objects-context-object-has-no-attribute-selected-objects)  Suggest post how you are attempting to run this in an addon.  You cannot simply import the code as above as an addon.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212545/import-multiple-stl-files-and-modify-them-in-one-go re importing STL files in an addon.